# How to design my own septic tank filter

Tags: septic, filter, baffling

My building has septic tank on its southeast corner.

I have no manhole cover, i.e, upward/eastward/westward/northward access to my septic tank, it's all covered.

I can access it through south wall only. So both input and output (200 mm capped pipe to allow tankers to suck the septic) is on the same side which is south.

I'm trying to make a hole in the south wall, (it's the only way) and take the filtered water to percolation tank so that water can be drained easily and I don't have to pay for septic tanker lorry once in two months.

[image]

To take the filtered septic water we can use baffle filter but it's quite vertical in and it would have to be placed inside septic tank and sealed with cement from south side wall.

But after sometime if baffle filter gets clogged, I will have to get rid of the cement coverings from the south wall and take out the filter and clean and keep it inside again.

[image]

I'm wondering if I could have some kind of standard inline filter which is outside of the building south wall. It would then be easy for me to clean in case if it gets clogged.

Can someone recommend me a wise idea to deal with my circumstance?

Can I place vertical baffle filter horizontally to the pipe outside of the south wall? Would it work properly?

**Update 1:**

I mean to say there is a room on the north wall so I can't break the floor and break the north wall of septic tank. Beyond east wall I don't have any land left , on the west there is another room .. so I can't take drain pipe from septic tank there as well. South wall is road facing side so I can take drain pipe from there only. Besides the septic tank inlet is also on the south wall, Ideally I should be having 2 brick walls from south to north inside septic tank so the water than arrives in Northen most chamber will be free from scum or sludge and I should be taking water from here to cess pit. But my septic tank has only one chamber. I want to have a filter outside the south wall which is effective and I should be able to clean the filter once in 6 months.

**Update 2:**

Here is an excerpt from [Government code](http://cpheeo.gov.in/upload/uploadfiles/files/engineering_chapter9.pdf) for areas where there's no Sewage Treatment Plant or Public Sewage line is not there.

> A septic tank system is a typical on-site treatment facility that
> consists of a septic tank and a soak pit and employs two technologies:
> the first is anaerobic treatment and the second is the methods of
> letting treated sewage penetrate the ground. It shows stable
> performance, provided that the water temperature is kept suitable to
> digestion and the soil has good permeability.  Part A: Engineering 9 -
> 2 CHAPTER 9: ON-SITE SANITATION However, the septic tank reduces BOD
> up to 50%, so if underground penetration is impossible due to high
> groundwater levels, rocky strata, non-availability of land for
> soak-pit, another method must be employed to hygienically treat sewage
> passing through the septic tank such as anaerobic filter and contact
> aeration. When this system is applied to an urban area with high
> population density, care must be taken not to have a negative effect
> on the surrounding environment.

Comment: If you have to get it pumped every 2 months then you either have a completely failed drain field, or what you have is not really a septic tank, but more of a holding tank. Is the photo in your question yours, or is it just something you just pulled off the web?

Comment: not sure what the north - south have to do with anything.

Comment: @brhans - It's something I took from web to give an idea about how usual baffle filter looks like in septic tank

Comment: @Ruskes - Please find the update

Comment: are you planing a single stage or multiple stage filter

Comment: Be sure what you're proposing is legal in your location.

Comment: @Ruskes - I'm happy to have multiple stage filter because it could give me better purified water.

Comment: @jwh20 - Cleaned water is allowed to be percolated as per the local code.

Comment: Ok, just wanting to help you avoid a potentially expensive mistake.

Comment: @jwh20 - Paying once in two month for the truck to empty out the septic tank is not economically feasible in long run so I'm thinking to spend some money now to safely dispose the filterred septic water safely into ground via a cess pit.  Ofcouse health concerns are to be respected.

Comment: You missed my point.  Doing something that is mot permitted by your local authority may subject you to significant fines as well as a requirement to undo what you have done and even bring the entire system up to current building standards.

Comment: Drained easily to where? Percolation underground in an established leech field is one thing, but having a pipe where you're going to pump it out onto the neighbor's lawn or a storm drain may be another thing altogether.

Comment: @jwh20 - you are right ,it made me dig through the codes. I have attached government code in my question , which permits in the absence of no public sewage connection.

Comment: @spuck - There's not much space for leech field so I'm trying to  send the filtered and disinfected water into percolation tank.

Answer (score 2):

You have to design a multi step system which will address so many factors like Air pressure , Pathogen , Scum , Sludge , Water overflow, odour  , mosquitoes, leach, insects , keeping the bio activity alive in septic tank etc..

**First Step: Membrane filter**

I can give you a rough idea Just build a concrete cube with Baffle filter standing vertically in it and keep a air tight concrete slab on top of it.

Connect a pipe directly from your septic tank to the cube

- Have a RO(Reverse Osmosis) membrane on the pipe which is on cube side. So you can change the membrane once in a year and the water that comes to the cube in mostly clean and free of bacteria.
- Have a Super sponge next the RO filter , this helps too
- Have a metal filter as well

Have all this one after another.

Purpose:
Remove pathogens and solids

**Second filter: Baffle filter**

Install a Baffle filter and keep it upright in the centre of the cube and connect the lower end of filter to the pipe which leads to cess pit.

Purpose:

If RO membrane fails then this can atleast keep the solids away from entering into cesspit.

If possible have a Geofabric filter of 5 GSM on top of this RO membrane with some gape in it.

if solid enters into cesspit then over the time. Cess pit will fail as well.

**Third Step: Disinfectant dripper**

- Have a dripper attached to each cesspit serially and have the liquid coming from a small liquid storage.
- Pour a *baking soda* mixed water first week of the month and let it drip away the whole month.
- Pour *boric acid* mixed water second week of the month and let it drip away the next month.
- Pour *Chlorine* mixed water third week of the month and let it drip away the next month.

Purpose:
To kill the pathogens and keep rats, cockroaches , termite ants,mosquito larva, mosquito away.

Note:

The water should not go back to septic tank from Cesspit or else the biological digesting system inside will die

**Fourth Step: Mushroom air vent(Charcoal) & Drain pipe vent**

- Have a mushroom air vent and load charcoal into that so odour is kept
  away.
- Have a drain pipe through which you can pump the water out if
  required.

Purpose:
To keep the odour away and pump the water when required

**Fifth Step:Increase Bio Activity**

- Make sure you never use acid on cleaning WC
- Drop inoculum bacterial culture liquid into your WC once in 6 months.

**Sixth step: Water tight cess pit**

- Cess pit should be sealed completely with concrete on top and sides , so rain water can't get and if water level increases during the rainy season you can prevent the water from leaking above the ground.

**Disclaimer:**

Take all this with pinch of a salt.Good luck

**Note:**

- Cesspits should be kept on the side where tankers can access it easily.
- The greatest risks of pathogen exposure to human and cause subsequent illness comes from below

  - Being unprotected when Emptying out the cesspit
  - Through contamination of ground water and use the ground water from near by areas
  - When a cesspit is overflowing due to plumbing system malfunction or infiltration of rain water into cesspit

[Reference[Global Water Pathogen Project]](https://www.waterpathogens.org/book/cesspits-and-soakpits)

Best thing to do is kill pathogens in cesspit with drip method I mentioned above

**Update:**

Like you said RO Membrane and other sponge filter will need more maintenance so

Please find my below sketch , it'll be low maintenance

[image]

**Chamber 1:**

It'll stop most of the sediments and scums.

**Chamber 2:**

Buy a good Effluent filter ,it's bit expensive but it's definitely worth it or else your percolation tank's bottom will get sealed with sludge over the time.

[image]

**Chamber 3:**

Fill this chamber with charcoals and also have inlet dripping pipe for chlorinating the water.

Don't forget to have a inlet dripping pipe for each percolation tank as well.

This will disinfect and finish off the alagaes.

FYI:

Make sure 3 chamber's outlet is lower than it's inlet by 6 inches or 1 feet. so there's no issue of water backing up and killing off the bio culture in your actual septic tank or don't do the chlorination in 3rd chamber just do it individually in all 4 cess pits

**Update:**
DIY Effluent filter

- Buy a Stainless Steel 316 ( marine grade ) Mesh and make it like a sock.

[image]

- Buy a non organic cloth and seal the bottom of the sock

[image]

- Similarly make a collar on the top of the sock with non-organic fabric
- Get a small handle made of SS 316 and sew it with the collar and top of the mesh

Make sure the T's height is 1 or half feet and SS 316 sock's height is 2 or 3 feet so the filter sticks out

[image]

so you don't have to clean the fillet for at-least 2 years.

[image]

FYI:

Make sure the micron of SS 316 mesh is 1600 to 2000. So you won't have to clean the filter often and this is the standard size in domestic effluent filters( EF-4)

[Reference for DIY Filter](http://tuxgraphics.org/npa/septic-tank-filter-retrofit/)

**Update 2:**

Two more ways to handle the solid

- Biological underflow drain ( In cess pit)

  - Just connect underflow pipes to all the cesspits
  - Fill the cesspits with bio coated material so when water comes up , bio matter grows and that keeps the water clean

The only problem is it can get clogged and cause overflow if not maintained properly

- Upflow anaerobic filter ( Before cess pit )

  - It involves an chamber that's air tight.
  - Basically the first chamber and second chamber should be connected at bottom
  - Second chamber should have a filter medium completely from bottom to top and there should be a outlet pipe above the filter medium , basically this filters all the solids both settleable and unsettable and as the water goes slowly in the airless chamber the bio matter also gets digested by bacteria.
  - If you could use chlorinator on the water that comes out of  this chamber then that should be it.

Reference [1](https://www.indiawaterportal.org/sites/default/files/iwp2/Code_of_practice_for_installation_of_septic_tanks____Part_1___Design_criteria_and_construction___Bureau_of_Indian_Standards___1986.PDF) [2](https://www.indiawaterportal.org/sites/default/files/iwp2/Code_of_practice_for_installation_of_septic_tanks_Part_2_Secondary_treatment_and_disposal_of_septic_tank_effluentent___Bureau_of_Indian_Standards___1985.PDF)

Update 3: Sand filter ( Gravity)

You could probably use slow sand filter. So like in the above update up flow chamber , you may use sand filter chamber

- Have a slotted pipe at the bottom of the chamber
- Quarter of the chamber has to be filled with gravel ( Coarse at the bottom and fine gravel at the top)
- In the remaining space , fill exactly half of it with sand( Coarse sand just above the gravel and finer to the top )

So when the water comes , to this chamber .. the filter medium ( Sand ) filters solids, pathogens and let the water infiltrate to the support medium which is nothing but our gravel then through gravel water passes into the slots of pipe and that's our filtered outlet.

Downsides of Filter:
You will have to clean it once in a while to keep it working ( I mean once in 3 months usually)

**Best filter medium:**

- Sand
- Activated charcoal
- Cinder
- Slag

**Disinfection:**

You could buy chlorine tablets and drop into the cess pit directly through air vent.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , it has given me some ideas. But my doubt is if chlorine is dropped into cesspit like you mentioned above... if water backs up to septic tank won't it kill the Biological system in septic tank ?

Comment: Other than this the filters like RO membrane , Super Sponge .. will get blocked with dirt.

Comment: Gravity filter is the sustainable long standing filter , so make use of gravity in the Chambers

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How do I add chlorine ? Manually ? or How frequently ? I am looking for a maintenance less approach ?

Comment: Not sure about how much chlorine should be mixed as well ?

Comment: You have to do ground water test to find PH. Based on PH value , you have to decide the dosage. You may find some easy water test kit online

Comment: Usually 4g bleaching powder( which has 33 percent chlorine) is used for 1000 Litres of water.  You can mix the bleaching powder in water ( Use hand gloves anyways ) and just take the mixed water and leave out any undissolved solids.

Comment: Have a hanging bucket and have connection with all 4 cesspits so when you pour the liquid into the bucket it goes into all 4 cess pits. But if you want to go mechanical way , you will have to buy chlorinator and route all the water through a metal container tank.. that's where chlorination happens. People don't buy this kind of chlorinator for in house sewage water treatment.. It's usually used in industrial appliances not home as far as I am aware

Comment: This is not so much manua like opening the end cap from each cess pit and poruing. we're using gravity to deliver it all cess pits

Comment: Thanks for the replies ,If I am dripping chlorine regularly .. won't the chlorine level increase and  I read chlorination can corrode the RCC and subsequently reach the rebar and cause structural damage.

Comment: I think you can go for UV Chamber which don't have any overdose issue or any byproduct issue. Let me update the answer with few more information